# Parallelism between instructions in TMS320C3x assembler

Tags: assembly, embedded, signal-processing, texas-instruments

Please consider the following instruction:

```
mpyf3 *ar0+, *ar1+, r0 || addf3 r0, r1, r1
```

The first instruction is equal to `r0 = *ar0++ * *ar1++` and the second instruction is equal to `r1 = r0 + r1`. However, what's the value of `r0` in the second instruction? There are two options:

1. `r0` is the value of `r0` before the parallel instruction
2. `r0` is the result of the first instruction

What's correct?

---

Moreover, how would I parallelize a simple filter such as the following one

```
void emg_filter(int const* a0, int* a1)
{
    int const N = ...;
    int result = 0;
    for (; N > 0; --N)
        result += *a0++;
    *a1 = result/N;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the TMS320C3x Users's Guide documentation for the `MPYF3||ADDF3` instruction:

> A floating-point multiplication and a floating-point addition are
>   performed in parallel. All registers are read at the beginning and
>   loaded at the end of the execute cycle. If one of the parallel
>   operations (MPYF3) reads from a register and the operation being
>   performed in parallel (ADDF3) writes to the same register, then MPYF3
>   accepts the contents of the register as input before it is modified by
>   the ADDF3.

Answer (score 0):

Both are done in parallel, so it is (1.): the `r0` in `addf3 r0, x, x` is NOT the output of `mpyf3 x, x, r0`.
Typically you use it in a loop, so if you repeat this instruction several times, the `addf3` is using the `r0` that was computed during the previous cycle by `multf3`.

Not sure what you question is with the loop, but you should be able to use a repeat single instruction (RPTS). Also, it's better to multiply by the constant (1/N), rather than dividing by N.

Answer (score -2):

Then I think it would be the problem of precedence, in most case they are left-to-right, and I think multiply would be calculated first, because in C, multiply is more prior than add instruction by one level.

Comment: We're not talking about precedence here or whether the example is sensible or not. It's a question about how parallel instructions are implemented in TMS320C3x assembler.